# PyAthena - Invalid length for parameter RoleArn

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, boto3, amazon-athena, pyathena

I am trying to use Python, PyAthena, and SQLAlchemy to connect to Athena.

When trying to define a SQLAlchemy cursor:

```
from pyathena import connect

cursor = connect(
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key, 
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_key, 
    s3_staging_dir=s3_staging_dir,
    region_name=aws_region,
    schema_name=schema_name, 
    role_arn=aws_workgroup
).cursor()
```

I get this error:

```
ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid length for parameter RoleArn, value: 14, valid min length: 20
```

The string for `aws_workgroup`, which is correct and I cannot change, is 14 characters long. I came across [this issue in botocore](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1465) from 2018, but it refers to aws-visualizer, and I don't know what that is or if I'm using it (or boto, for that matter).

If I remove `role_arn` from the cursor, that code will run, but then I get this permissions error when trying to execute a query:

```
DatabaseError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: 
You are not authorized to perform: athena:StartQueryExecution on the resource. 
After your AWS administrator or you have updated your permissions, please try again.
```

I have verified the credentials in other applications, so it is not an issue with the credentials provided.

How do I fix the `RoleArn` error? Or is there another method to connect to Athena in Python that gets around this?

Comment: Refer to this line on how you can connect https://github.com/condor723/python-scripts/blob/16386a90f3deaf81412dabd5f74bbc6ab3bd5ba0/athenapythontest/app.py#L91 and let me know if it helps so that I can add this code as answer

Comment: Thanks - I've tried that syntax and without the `role_arn=aws_workgroup` line, I get an error also.